# How to write a recursive function that returns a list made up of squares of the elements of lst?

Tags: python, list, recursion, computer-science, perfect-square

Im not sure how to get my recursion to work properly or keep from infinitely repeating. 
This is what i have so far:

```
def listSquareR(lst):
    if len(lst)== 1:
        return lst[0]**2
    else:
        return lst[0]**2+[listSquareR(lst[1:])]
```

last return line is obviously wrong

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
def listSquare(L):
  if L: return [L[0]**2] + listSquare(L[1:])
  else: return []
```

An even shorter version (as Cristian Ciupitu mentions below) is:

```
def listSquare(L):
  return [L[0]**2] + listSquare(L[1:]) if L else []
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `return [L[0]**2] + listSquare(L[1:]) else []`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Sorry, that's not syntactically valid

Comment: @CristianCiupitu You forgot the `if L` part just before the `else`. Otherwise, good one!

Comment: Haste makes waste :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost right, but the key is to mind your types. In your code:

```
def listSquareR(lst):
    if len(lst)== 1:
        return lst[0]**2  # Returning a number
    else:
        return lst[0]**2+[listSquareR(lst[1:])]  # Returning a number plus a list of a list
```

We just need two small fixes:

```
def listSquareR(lst):
    if len(lst)== 1:
        return [lst[0]**2]  # Returning a list
    else:
        return [lst[0]**2] + listSquareR(lst[1:])  # Returning a list plus a list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def SquareArea(width):
if width == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return SquareArea(width-1) + (2*width-1)
```

This is a recursive function I've recently used to find the area of a square.
And since the area of a square is Side*Side, one can use it to find the square of any function.
Now all that is required of you is to make a loop, eg:

```
for i in range (list):
```

and implement this function on i
Or maybe use while loop.

```
newList=[]
length = len(list)
while i != length:
   newList.append(SquareArea(i))
```

And then return the newList